# Am I correctly determining the convergence or divergence of these series: $\sum \frac{1}{n(\ln(n))^{5/4})}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms

I'm doing online homework, which immediately tells me if I got it right or wrong, and I got the following question correct, but I just want to make sure I'm getting it correct for the right reasons.

It asks me to determine the convergence of divergence of the given series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty   \left(\frac{1}{n(\ln(n))^{5/4})}\right)$$

Literally all I'm doing is the p-series test, so I'm looking at the exponent in the denominator, which is 5/4 > 1 and thus I'm saying that it converges. However, I get the feeling that there is more to it than that and that I actually need to do some sort of evaluating, but I'm not sure because the question is online and it just asks if it is converging or diverging, so all I know is that my answer is correct, I don't actually know if my reasoning is correct. Is that are all these is to the p-series test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is not correct. *Hint:* Note that $\dfrac{1}{x(\ln x)^{5/4}} = \left(-4(\ln x)^{-1/4}\right)'$ and use the Cauchy-Maclaurin integral test.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cauchy's Condensation test:

$$\frac{2^n}{2^n\log^{5/4}(2^n)}=\frac1{\log^{5/4}2}\frac1{n^{5/4}}$$

and since the series with general term from the right converges (why?), also ours does.